# How to open image immediate to the downloading of the image

Tags: xamarin.forms, domdocument

I am using xamarin.forms for android and iOS apps. Here I am able to save the images and documents by creating a personal folder for the applications. But the requirement is after the image/ document is downloaded it should open automatically without going to that folder manually. How to do that for android and iOS.

Saving image/Documents 
for android:

```
  byte[] respuesta = Android.Util.Base64.Decode(fileBytes, Android.Util.Base64.Default);

                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(fileFullPath, respuesta);
```

in iOS:

```
if (extension.ToLower() == ".pdf")
            {

                byte[] encodedDataAsBytes = DecodeUrlBase64(DataString);

                string documentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);

                string finalPath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, Path.GetFileName(fileFullPath));

                File.WriteAllBytes(finalPath, encodedDataAsBytes);
            }

            if(extension.ToLower() == ".png" || extension.ToLower() == ".jpg" || extension.ToLower() == ".jpeg" || extension.ToLower() == ".gif")
            {
                byte[] encodedDataAsBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(DataString);

                NSData data = NSData.FromArray(encodedDataAsBytes);

                var someImage= UIImage.LoadFromData(data);

                someImage.SaveToPhotosAlbum((image, error) =>
                {
                    var o = image as UIImage;
                    Console.WriteLine("error: " + error);
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

In Android: First you have to get file from file path that you have stored in private folder of your android device.

```
File file = new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath(), "fileName.png");
```

Then to use it you have convert it into URI path as below.

```
Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(DownloadShareActivity.this, SHARED_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY, file);
```

Comment: Thanks, @Mike, I will check with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DependencyService` to get a byte array to show it into an Image Control like this:

In your core project:

```
public interface IGetBytesImagesService
{
    byte[] GetBytes(string path);
}
```

In your Android project:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(GetBytesImagesService))]
public class GetBytesImagesService : IGetBytesImagesService
{
    public async byte[] GetBytes(string path)
    {
         return File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);;
    }
}
```

In your iOS project:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(GetBytesImagesService))]
public class GetBytesImagesService : IGetBytesImagesService
{
    public async byte[] GetBytes()
    {
         return File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
    }
}
```

Now in your `xaml.cs` file you can set this byte array to `Image.Source` like this:

```
var stream = new MemoryStream(DependencyService.Get<IGetBytesImagesService>().GetBytes(filePath));
yourImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I wanted to open that from the folder, For example, My documents will be stored in `/Users/UserName/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A3BC6BE2-8CEB-489F-91A4-72362B7DFB7E/data/Containers/Data/Application/AB45DR45-3166-48C1-B26E-CC74B62FB70C/Documents/send.png"` , so, when the download is completed that file from that folder should be open.

Comment: I have tried of using the `Device.OpenUri("/Users/UserName/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A3BC6BE2-8CEB-489F-91A4-72362B7DFB7E/data/Containers/Data/Application/AB45DR45-3166-48C1-B26E-CC74B62FB70C/Documents/send.png")` but there is no navigation to the to that folder.

Comment: Do you want show in your app? or do you want use gallery to show your image? If you want show it in your app just use this: `byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(yourPath);` and return a byteArray to show it into an Image control.

Comment: The image will be downloaded into the gallery. So, what I wanted is after the image is saved to the gallery the app has to navigate to the gallery there user should see the image what they have downloaded.